# Spring Data JPA: How to update multiple column with different value

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data jpa for creating services. I want to know about how to update multiple rows at one time with different values In spring data JPA. previously I updating record in table but only one row I updated.

I am not getting idea how to update multiple rows with different values on one save button click. How to receive parameters from front end

[image]

This is my table structure. I want to update percentage column. `nRoomInvestigatorMappingId` is varying may be next time I have 4 id with total percentage equals to 100(eg. 30,50,10,10 like this).

So Can any one tell me how to take input from front end and how to save?

Comment: What are you sending from the frontend?

Comment: nRoomInvestigatorMappingId and percentage